# Assembly ddd debugger, how to observe memory contents under the address given as (%ebx)

Tags: assembly, i386

I am writing a code that is supposed to remove spaces from a string and return a string without spaces. The code is supposed to do the following:

- firstly copy the address of the first letter in the string to `eax` and
  `ebx` and a variable called 'address'
- then take one char from `(%ebx)` and check whether it is a space
- if in `(%ebx)` there is a space, increase `ebx` by `$1` so I get the next character
- if in `(%ebx)` was something else (not a space) then copy it into `eax`, then increase `eax` and `ebx` and process the next letter
- if `(%ebx) == 0` then I copy the initial address of a string (in variable address) into `%eax` and finish the function

I used ddd to see what is going on in registers (I copy `(%ebx)` into `%edx` to see what is in memory under the address written in `(%ebx)` and I get a very high number, instead of a number that could represent a character from the string that I try to process. 
I am afraid that there is some structural problem to my code that I cannot see and that I do not understand. 
The code returns exactly the same string that was created initially and does not remove any spaces.

Ignore a variable "zamiana", it will be used in the code when I solve problems with the removal of the spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char * usun_spacje(char * wsk, int zamiana);

int main()
{
    char* wskaznik = malloc(100);
    int zamiana = 0;
    sprintf(wskaznik, "%s", "abc  def   gh ijk");
    printf("This is a processed text %s \n", usun_spacje(wskaznik, zamiana));
}
```

Assembly code:

```
//usun_spacje(char * wsk, int zamiana);
.data
address: .long 0
changes: .long 0

# char -> 1
# int -> 4
# long -> 4 bytes 

.equ bufor,8
.equ change,12
#eax, ebx, ecx, edx
#eax - beginning address of a string, this register will be used to write processed characters
#ebx - beginning address of a string, this register will be used to read characters
#general conception - take letter from ebx, process (remove spaces), save in eax

.text
.type   usun_spacje, @function
.global usun_spacje

 usun_spacje:   
        PUSHL   %ebp
        MOVL    %esp, %ebp
        MOVL    bufor(%esp), %edx #temporarily use edx to store address of a string that we will process
        MOVL    %edx, address #remember the beginning address of a string that we are going to process, edx is free to use again
        MOVL    change(%esp), %ecx #remember the option whether I change to CAPS or not
        MOVL    %ecx, changes #ecx is free to use again
        #PUSHL   %ebx 
        MOVL    address, %eax #to write processed characters
        MOVL    address, %ebx #to read characters
loop:
        MOVL    (%ebx), %edx #for debugging purposes to see what is in memory under address given by ebx
        CMP     $' ', (%ebx) #is space?
        JE      delete_space #if a character under (%ebx) is space then remove it, if not, move from ebx into eax
        MOVL    (%ebx), %edx #take a character from (%ebx) and put temporarily into %edx
        MOVL    %edx, (%eax) #now move a character from %edx into (%eax), edx is free to be used again
   #okay, so we moved a character from (%ebx) to (%eax), so we increase memory addresses to process the next char
        ADDL    $1, %eax #next memory address
        ADDL    $1, %ebx #nest memory address
        CMP     $0, (%ebx) #is this the end of the string we process?
        JE      end #if it is the end of the string, jump to end
        JMP     loop #if not, continue
end:
        ADDL    $0, (%eax) #add 0 at the end of the string 
        MOVL    address, %eax #to return our new string, copy its beginning adress into eax
        #POPL    %ebx
        MOVL    %ebp, %esp #epilogue
        POPL    %ebp
        RET

delete_space:
        ADDL   $1, %ebx #increase the address in ebx
        JMP    loop #start analysis again
```

Comment: You load 4 bytes instead of 1.

Comment: I try using SHR $8, (%ebx) and then MOVB (%exb), %dl to get 1 byte each time, but it does not work. I also tried MOVB 1(%ebx), %dl, but also does not work correctly.

Comment: Just use `movb (%ebx), %dl` since you increment the pointer by one correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After some gruelling modifications, finally the code started working. Thank you for insightful remarks concerning registries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char * usun_spacje(char * wsk, int zamiana);

int main()
{
    char* wskaznik = malloc(100);
    int zamiana = 0;
    sprintf(wskaznik, "%s", "A      b      c  defg  hi j");
    printf("This is a processed text %s \n", usun_spacje(wskaznik, zamiana));
}
```

Assembly code:

```
//usun_spacje(char * wsk, int zamiana);
.data
address: .long 0
changes: .long 0

# char -> 1
# int -> 4
# long -> 4 bytes 

.equ bufor,8
.equ change,12
#eax, ebx, ecx, edx
#eax - beginning address of a string, this register will be used to write processed characters
#ebx - beginning address of a string, this register will be used to read characters
#general conception - take letter from ebx, process (remove spaces), save in eax

.text
.type   usun_spacje, @function
.global usun_spacje

usun_spacje:   
    PUSHL   %ebp
    MOVL    %esp, %ebp
    MOVL    bufor(%esp), %edx #temporarily use edx to store address of a string that we will process
    MOVL    %edx, address #remember the beginning address of a string that we are going to process, edx is free to use again
    MOVL    change(%esp), %ecx #remember the option whether I change to CAPS or not
    MOVL    %ecx, changes #ecx is free to use again
    PUSHL  %ebx 
    MOVL    address, %eax #to write processed characters
    MOVL    address, %ebx #to read characters

loop:
    MOVB    (%ebx), %dl
    CMPB    $0, %dl #is this the end of the string we process?
    JE      end #if it is the end of the string, jump to end
    CMPB    $' ', %dl #is space?
    JE      delete_space #if a character under (%ebx) is space then remove it, if not, move from ebx into eax
#module to change letters into CAPS
    CMP      $0, %ecx
    JE       continue
    CMPB     $'a', %dl
    JAE      change_letters
 continue:
 #move processed letter into destination string (the same string actually)
    MOVB    %dl, (%eax) #save a character in the resulting string
    ADD     $1, %eax #next memory address OR INC
    ADD     $1, %ebx #next memory address OR INC
    JMP     loop #if not, continue
end:
    MOVB    $0, %dl
    MOVB    %dl, (%eax) 
    MOVL    address, %eax #to return our new string, copy its beginning adress into eax
    POPL    %ebx
    MOVL    %ebp, %esp #epilogue
    POPL    %ebp
    RET

#additional lines
delete_space:
    INC    %ebx #increase the address in ebx
    JMP    loop #start analysis again

change_letters:
    ADD    $-32, %dl
    JMP    continue
```